# Update con un from

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

**Quisiera saber en que me estoy equivocando  en mi consulta SQL**

```
update 
   tabla_c
set 
   tabla_c.precio = tabla_c.precio *    talba_b.porcentaje
FROM
   cat_marca as tabla_c inner join cat_concepto as tabla_a on   tabla_c.id_concepto = tabla_a.id_concepto
inner join cat_depreciacion as tabla_b on tabla_a.id_depreciacion =  tabla_b.id
Where
   tabla_c.nombre_marca = neffos
```

Comment: `talba_b.porcentaje`? imagino que debería ser `tabla_b` en todo caso.

Comment: Cual es el error que te muestra?

Comment: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'inner join cat_concepto as tabla_a on tabla_c.id_concepto = tabla_a.id_concepto
' Ã  la ligne 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQL la sentencia UPDATE sirve para actualizar los datos de una sola tabla, así es que no soporta el "JOIN" con otras tablas, al menos no en forma natural

La sintaxis standard ANSI es:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Creo, que la reformulación de la sentencia debe ser:

```
UPDATE cat_marca as tabla_c
   SET tabla_c.precio = (SELECT tabla_c.precio * tabla_b.porcentaje
                         FROM   cat_concepto as tabla_a
                         INNER  JOIN cat_depreciacion as tabla_b 
                                  ON tabla_a.id_depreciacion =  tabla_b.id
                         WHERE   tabla_c.id_concepto = tabla_a.id_concepto)
WHERE  tabla_c.nombre_marca = neffos
```

Comment: Creo que estas dando información errónea, el `Join` en un `Update`, si es posible.

Comment: lo comente: "La sintaxis standard ANSI"